# Calculate average of a list of datetime objects

Tags: datetime

I would like to calculate the mean time of a list of datetime objects. Here is a piece of code for testing:

```
import datetime as dt

test_dates = []
d = dt.datetime(2015,1,1,10) # startdate
while d < dt.datetime(2015,1,1,17): # enddate 
    test_dates.append(d)
    d += dt.timedelta(hours=1)
```

For these test_dates the result would be: `avg_time = datetime.datetime(2015,1,1,13,0)`

How do I implement this? Do I have to convert to timestamps before?
Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would convert to timestamps:

```
dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(sum(d.timestamp() for d in test_dates)/len(test_dates))
```